# How can I make this REGEX cleaner?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this regex I made to compare OS names to a line in a VMX file.  It started out as separate `elsif` statments, but I ended up making into a single `if` statment.  Anyhow, here is the code; I am trying to find a way to make the code cleaner, but it put each match on a separate line; it no longer works.

```
elsif ($vmx_file =~ m/guestOSAltName\s+=\s"Microsoft\sWindows\sServer\s2003,Web\sEdition"|"Microsoft\sWindows\sSmall\sBusiness\sServer\s2003"|"Microsoft\sWindows\s2000\sAdvanced\sServer"|"Microsoft\sWindows\s2000\sServer"|"Microsoft\sWindows\s2000\sProfessional"|"Microsoft\sWindows\s98"|"Microsoft\sWindows\s95"|"Microsoft\sWindows\sNT\s4"/) {
            $virtual_machines{$vm}{"Architecture"} = "32-bit";
```

Updated code as per suggestions,

```
elsif ($vmx_file =~ m/guestOSAltName\s+=\s"Microsoft\sWindows\sServer\s2003,Web\sEdition|Small\sBusiness\sServer\s2003|"2000\sAdvanced\sServer|2000\sServer|2000\sProfessional|98|95|NT\s4/) {
            $virtual_machines{$vm}{"Architecture"} = "32-bit";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `/x` modifier to make your regex prettier, if not actually cleaner.

```
$vmx_file =~ m/guestOSAltName\s+=
    \s("Microsoft\sWindows\sServer\s2003,Web\sEdition"
     | "Microsoft\sWindows\sSmall\sBusiness\sServer\s2003"
     | "Microsoft\sWindows\s2000\sAdvanced\sServer"
     | "Microsoft\sWindows\s2000\sServer"
     | "Microsoft\sWindows\s2000\sProfessional"
     | "Microsoft\sWindows\s98"
     | "Microsoft\sWindows\s95"
     | "Microsoft\sWindows\sNT\s4")/x
```

When you look at it like this, the improvements Robokop and Konstantin Gredeskoul suggested become
 obvious:

```
$vmx_file =~ m/guestOSAltName\s+=
    \s"Microsoft\sWindows\s
     (     Server\s2003,Web\sEdition
         | Small\sBusiness\sServer\s2003
         | 2000\s( (Advanced\s)?Server | Professional )
         | 9[85]
         | NT\s4
     )
       "/x
```

Comment: Wow that regex expression is TINY now.

Comment: Works perfect, I award the "Answer" to you.

Answer (score 5):

You might not want a regex at all, for efficiency as well as clarity reasons.  One option would be to capture the string outside the if block and match by hash keys:

```
#this could be offloaded to a constants file or some such
%architecture_by_os = (
    "Microsoft Windows Server 2003,Web Edition" => "32-bit",
    "Microsoft Windows Small Business Server 2003" => "32-bit",
    #etc.
)

$vmx_file =~ m/guestOSAltName\s+=\s(.*)/;
$virtual_machine{$vm}{Architecture} = $architecture_by_os{$1};
```

Comment: Wow that is a really good idea, never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

You can start by doing something with the Microsoft Windows matching and then the rest like:

```
Microsoft\sWindows\s(Server\s2003,Web\sEdition|Small\SBussines...)
```

Comment: Great idea! I will start with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use interpolation in the pattern to make it more readable:

```
my $names = join '|', @names;
if ($vmx_file =~ m/guestOSAltName\s+=\s(?:$names)) {
    $virtual_machines{$vm}{Architecture} = "32-bit";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parenthesis to group similar items in a regex so you don't have to repeat "Microsoft\sWindows" every time.  You should also use ? to indicate an optional or possibly missing item such as (\sWeb\sEdition)?.

(line breaks are for clarity)

```
m/guestOSAltName\s+=\s"Microsoft\sWindows\s?(Server\s2003(\sWeb\sEdition)?|
Small\sBusiness\sServer\s2003|
2000\sAdvanced\sServer|
2000\sServer|
2000\sProfessional
98|
NT\s4)"/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried line breaks like that and it failed to match the pattern on all of them. Not sure why.

Comment: It did not work because I did not have the "()" surrounding the part of the expression.

Comment: I also like Eugene's answer which uses an array of names to match against.